# How to remove an item using class? : javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made a table to show some items and i want it to be cleared once i press the clear button.
Now the main problem is that my tr that i want to remove does'nt take tbody as its parent.
Here's my html:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="stuffCarrier"></tbody>
</table>
```

and here's my javascript to remove the items:

```
document.getElementById("clearList").onclick = function () {
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("removeds")).forEach((e, i, arr) => {
    document.getElementById("stuffCarrier").removeChild(e);
    console.log(i, e, e.parentElement, arr);
});
localStorage.removeItem("CarriedStuff");
```

And here's my javascript how i added the items:

```
    const stuffCarrier = document.getElementById("stuffCarrier");
stuffCarrier.innerHTML = `<tr>
<th class="stuffs">Quantity</th>
<th class="stuffs" style="color:red">Stuff</th>
<th class="stuffs" style="color:chartreuse">Cost</th>
</tr>
`;

showStuff.forEach(e => {
    stuffCarrier.innerHTML += `<tr class="stuffs removeds">
    <td>${e[2]}</td>
    <td style="color:blue">${e[0]}</td>
    <td style="color:white">${e[1] * e[2]}</td>
    </tr>
    `;
});
```

Comment: Kindly post full code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("removeds")).forEach(d=>d.remove())
```

Comment: This answer needs more of an explanation. A single line of code is not considered a good answer.

Comment: Thanks bro. And sorry to others as i forgot to tell that i could even use the  `<tr>
<th class="stuffs">Quantity</th>
<th class="stuffs" style="color:red">Stuff</th>
<th class="stuffs" style="color:chartreuse">Cost</th>
</tr>
`;
but the problem was that i also had to make a button to delete a specific item

Comment: Sorry again! For my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

First try to add tr as childElement of `stuffCarrier` like this:

```js
const stuffCarrier = document.getElementById("stuffCarrier");
childElement = `<tr>
<th class="stuffs">Quantity</th>
<th class="stuffs" style="color:red">Stuff</th>
<th class="stuffs" style="color:chartreuse">Cost</th>
</tr>
`;

stuffCarrier.appendChild(childElement);
```

Even within the for loop. Then I think you will be able to remove tr as `removeChild()`.

Or you can directly remove all the selected elements like this:

`Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("removeds")).forEach(d=>d.remove())` without using `removeChild()` method.

I hope it helps.